# How to put ASP.NET site offline if critical services are not available

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, architecture

How would you go about placing the site off-line if the database is down or the database adapter is missing / failed to load / etc.?

I am asking in the context of ASP.NET MVC 3 but this can apply for any ASP.NET site.

Let's say somewhere around App_Start you load an assembly for data access and this is missing and/or something else fails. In this case the site can't actually function.

I'm looking for a decent/elegant way to place the site in "Maintenance mode" just like [App_Offline.htm](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2005/10/06/426755.aspx) works.

Comment: Define maintenance mode?  Just take the entire application offline?

Comment: Yes! Maintenance mode takes the whole application offline and for any web request presents the same web page stating that this is under maintenance mode.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
catch (ReallyBadException ex) {
    Utilities.EmailAdministrator();
    File.Copy(@"c:\templates\App_Offline.htm", @"c:\path\to\website\App_Offline.htm");
}
```

Comment: oh... so I don't get to escape from creating the App_offline.htm file

Comment: You wanted something just like `App_Offline.htm`, so why not use `App_Offline.htm`?  What do you have against it?  What would so-called 'maintenance mode' look like to you?

Comment: No, mellamokb, I am not against it :)  I am just asking if there would be anything more elegant, easier or more straight-forward. If this is ideal than be it! :)

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Circuit breaker pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circuit_breaker_design_pattern)

Maybe too general for you (i am not sure if you are looking for conceptual solution or ASP.NET specific) but it can help you.

Comment: tons of links available. here you have more .net examples: http://timross.wordpress.com/2008/02/10/implementing-the-circuit-breaker-pattern-in-c/